# How to run Generator Functions in Parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

Assuming I have a Koa web server with an endpoint like this:

```
const perform = require(...); // some generator function

exports.endpoint = function* () {

    var results = yield getResults();

    // Respond the results
    this.body = results;
}

exports.getResults = function* () {

    var actions = [...];
    var results = [];

    for (var action of actions) {

        var result = yield perform(action);

        results.push(results);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Now the client will get the respond after ALL the actions are performed obviously. but the things is each action is dependent on the completion of the previous.

Is there a way to execute them in parallel?

Note: Turning them to Promises is not an option, unless I can somehow return the results, and not resolve() them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`co` turns the generator function to Promises, and executes them async. `Promise.all` waits for all of them to finish:

```
exports.getResults = function* () {

    var actions = [...];

    return yield Promise.all(actions.map(function(action) { 
        return co(function*() { 
            return yield perform(action); 
        } 
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the generators are used as coroutines, by simulating the `async`/`await` flow, then you should be able to do:

```
var results = yield Promise.all(actions.map(action => perform(action)));
```

or even:

```
var results = yield Promise.all(actions.map(perform));
```

I'm not sure about the exact usage here but when you use generators with `co` or `Bluebird.coroutine` then you're already using promises, so you may as well use them more explicitly.

So, instead of:

```
exports.getResults = function* () {

    var actions = [...];
    var results = [];

    for (var action of actions) {

        var result = yield perform(action);

        results.push(results);
    }

    return results;
}
```

you can try:

```
exports.getResults = function* () {

    var actions = [...];

    return yield Promise.all(actions.map(perform));
}
```

Comment: Problem is `perform(action)` returns suspended Generator, and will not execute the actual `perform()`. When yielded then Koa (or Bluebird.coroutine I believe) actually executes the function.

Comment: In order to actually run the perform function I can use `co` lib, does this solution make sense?

`return yield Promise.all(actions.map(function(action) {
  return co(function*() {
   return yield perform(action);
  }
 }));`

Comment: @ShaiBen-Dor Yes, it makes sense, `co` is very good for things like that. You may also be able to use `co.wrap` (part of the `co` module) and coroutine from Bluebird - see http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using redux saga than follow this link

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RunningTasksInParallel/