# How do I send multiple queries from one endpoint with Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I am trying to query my database several times and construct an object which stores every response from my database in a field. Here is my code:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    var collection = db.get().collection('styles')
    var data = [];

    collection.distinct('make.name', (err, docs) => {
      data.push({'make': docs });
    });

    collection.distinct('model', (function (err, docs) {
        data.push({'model': docs });
    }))

    res.send(data);
});
```

Since NodeJS/Express is asynchronous, this isn't working as I would like. How can I reconstruct this endpoint to make several database calls (from the same collection) and return an object containing it?

Comment: You should use promises.

Comment: @SLaks, I understand the concept of Promises, yet I have never applied them. If you can post a code sample, I would mark your answer as correct.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-05/introducing-promises/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's more than one way to do it:

### Nested callbacks

Without promises you could nest the callbacks:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    var collection = db.get().collection('styles')
    var data = [];

    collection.distinct('make.name', (err, docs) => {
      if (err) {
        // ALWAYS HANDLE ERRORS!
      }
      data.push({'make': docs });
        collection.distinct('model', (function (err, docs) {
          if (err) {
            // ALWAYS HANDLE ERRORS!
          }
          data.push({'model': docs });
          res.send(data);
        }))
    });
});
```

This would be the easiest way, but note that it is not efficient if those two requests could be done in parallel.

### The `async` module

You can use the `async` module:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    var collection = db.get().collection('styles')
    var data = [];

    async.parallel({
      make: cb => collection.distinct('make.name', cb),
      model: cb => collection.distinct('model', cb),
    }, (err, responses) => {
      if (err) {
        // ALWAYS HANDLE ERRORS!
      }
      data.push({'make': responses.make });
      data.push({'model': responses.model });
      res.send(data);
    });
});
```

See: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel

But this may still not be the most convenient method.

### ES2017 `async`/`await`

The most flexible way of doing that if you have 30 calls to make would be to:

1. Use functions that return promises instead of functions that take callbacks
2. Use async/await if you can or at least generator based coroutines
3. Await on promises (or yield promises) when the logic needs to run in sequence
4. Use `Promise.all()` for anything that can be done in parallel

With async/await your code could look like this:

```
    // in sequence:    
    var make = await collection.distinct('make.name');
    var model = await collection.distinct('model');
    // use 'make' and 'model'
```

Or:

```
    // in parallel:
    var array = await Promise.all([
      collection.distinct('make.name'),
      collection.distinct('model'),
    ]);
    // use array[0] and array[1]
```

A big advantage of `async`/`await` is the error handling:

```
try {
  var x = await asyncFunc1();
  var array = await Promise.all([asyncFunc2(x), asyncFunc3(x)]);
  var y = asyncFunc4(array);
  console.log(await asyncFunc5(y));
} catch (err) {
  // handle any error here
}
```

You can only use it inside of a function created with the `async` keyword. For more info, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

For support in browsers, see:

- http://caniuse.com/async-functions

For support in Node, see:

- http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions

In places where you don't have native support for `async` and `await` you can use Babel:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/

or with a slightly different syntax a generator based approach like in `co` or Bluebird coroutines:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/co
- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html

See those answers for more info:

- [try/catch blocks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await/40886720#40886720)
- [node.js ~ constructing chained sequence of Promise resolves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238039/node-js-constructing-chained-sequence-of-promise-resolves/43238119#43238119)
- [How to run Generator Functions in Parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768461/how-to-run-generator-functions-in-parallel/42768639#42768639)
- [node.js ~ constructing chained sequence of Promise resolves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238039/node-js-constructing-chained-sequence-of-promise-resolves/43238119#43238119)
- [Using async/await + Bluebird to promisifyAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096728/using-async-await-bluebird-to-promisifyall/43096840#43096840)
- [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)

Comment: I have about 30 different calls to make; not only are they conditional, but there will be a nested nightmare. I appreciate your approach, however, it isn't efficient enough. I am trying to get parameters for a faceted search function available on my site.

Comment: @Moshe The most flexible solution for complex code would be async/await or generator based coroutines. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Promises

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    var collection = db.get().collection('styles');
    // Create promise for "make.name" query
    let firstQuery = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        collection.distinct('make.name', (err, docs) => {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(docs);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
    // Create promise for "model" query
    let secondQuery = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        collection.distinct('model', (function (err, docs) {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(docs);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        }))
    })
    // Run both queries at the same time and handle both resolve results or first reject
    Promise.all([firstQuery, secondQuery])
        .then((results) => {
            res.send({ "make.name": results[0], "model": results[1] });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // Catch error 
            res.send({});
        });
});
```

Also you can use destructuring in callback functions like that:

```
Promise.all([firstQuery, secondQuery])
    .then(([makeName, model]) => res.send({ "make.name": makeName, model }))
```

UPD: If you have a bunch of collection to request you can create an array of collections name, map it to promise requests and handle with Promise.all, for example

```
let collections = ["firstCollection", "secondCollection", "nCollection"];
let promises = collections.map((collectionName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        collection.distinct(collectionName, (err, docs) => {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(docs)
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    })
});
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => {
        // Do what you want to do
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // or catch 
    });
```

Comment: can you explain the difference between results[0] and results[1]? Does it follow.. results[2] ... results[n] for n calls?

Comment: @Moshe Sure. You have an array of Promises in `Promise.all` function. So in `.then` of `Promise.all` handler you have an array of arguments, passed to `resolve` callback in each `Promise` of input array in the same order that they were in the input array

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!