# Parallel asynchronous iteraor - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, async-iterator

Right now I have the following code:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const urls = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com']

async function* requests() {
  for (const url of urls) {
    yield axios.get(url)
  }
}

;(async () => {
  for await (const n of requests()) {
    console.log(n.config.url) // prints https://google.com and then https://yahoo.com
  }
})()
```

As is, the requests won't block the single thread of node, but they will happen in sequence. I'm wondering if it would be possible to change the code to force parallelism.

Comment: would [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) solve your problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How would I use Promise.all to parallelize things? I also need to use the response as they are available because we have a memory constrain.

Comment: in your case, if you `await Promise.all(requests())` it will return you an array with the resolved promises of `axios.get()`
So it will run all requests in parallel, and Promise.all() resolves when every Promise inside the iterator has resolved

Comment: That's not good enough, I can't hold every one of those responses in memory as I stated before. I need to use them as they are available, like a stream.

Comment: You can batch them, instead of every request, iterate every n requests. Or use rxjs

Comment: Can you elaborate with an answer @SrThompson?

Comment: Does this help @gos3 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768461/how-to-run-generator-functions-in-parallel

Comment: Also - this script `co` seems to be a nice approach https://github.com/tj/co#arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "simpler" no-deps way would be to batch them and yield every batch with `Promise.all`

```
import axios from 'axios'

const urls = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', 
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/1'
]

async function* requests(batchSize = 1) {
  let batchedRequests = [];
  for (const url of urls) {
    batchedRequests.push(axios.get(url));
    if (batchedRequests.length === batchSize) {
      yield Promise.all(batchedRequests);
      batchedRequests = [];
    }
  }
  if (batchedRequests.length) { //if there are requests left in batch
    yield Promise.all(batchedRequests);
  }
}

;(async () => {
  for await (const batch of requests(2)) {
    batch.forEach(n => console.log(n.config.url)) // prints https://google.com and then https://yahoo.com
  }
})()
```

You can use `rxjs` to achieve similar results, with the advantages that observables have in terms of flexibility, but it's another library and can be more complex if you're not familiar with reactive streams. Here is a detailed post I found on the topic: https://medium.com/@ravishivt/batch-processing-with-rxjs-6408b0761f39